# JQuery sortable portlets clear formatting inside

Tags: jquery, portlet

I'm using jQuery sortable portlets found here http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

The div class "portlet-content" apparently contains formatting that is really messing up my layout.  Is there any way to clear the formatting inside the portlet container?

Comment: Can you override the portlet-content class to format the content how you want it?

Comment: No, I tried that. Nothing seems to work, even redefining the css styles.  They seem to be overridden somehow.

Comment: You could try overriding the css with your own or even make a div inside the portlet-content and have css for that.